VisualSVN update hangs when running as background task
I have an SVN repo running on a windows server.  As a regular task, I need to update a local version of the repo on an unattended server, to ensure that the latest working copy is held.
I have created a powershell script to do this on the server, however whenever it gets to svn update, the script hangs.  There are no errors and no files get updated locally.
I have made sure the user has full control over the repo & also over the local directory containing the repo.
Is there any way of finding out what is causing this problem and also how to rectify it.

Add the '--non-interactive' option to the SVN commands in the script. And examine the output of this script.

And show the code of your script and how you run it from Task Scheduler
